# Php Facebook login script ends up in a redirect loop and does not login

Tags: php, facebook, loops, redirect, authentication

This code always runs the last else part and redirects to the login URL provided by facebook api. If i print the $user variable, it just shows 0 everytime.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'app id',
  'secret' => 'app secret',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();   
  $_SESSION['logouturl'] = $logoutUrl;
  $_SESSION['user'] = $user_profile['name'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $user_profile['id'];
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'facebook';
  header('Location: index.php');
} else 
{
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xx',
  'secret' => 'xx',
  'scope' => 'read_stream, email'
));



if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, email'
);



$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

make sure your app setting on Facebook is good, rest is looking fine and if you have minor problem in you app setting on Facebook developer console  it wont work specially domain name and domain url settings